# How do I keep Entity Framework from saving unmodified navigational properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

**EDIT:** It was solved by setting

```
aUpdate.b = null;
aUpdate.c = null;
```

before calling update. But this does not seem like the right way to do it.

Also, currently the way I'm saving is:

```
Set.Update(model);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT II:**
Where I'm including the related entities:

```
protected override IQueryable<A> GetQueryWithIncludes(Include level)
{
  var q = Query;
  if (level == Include.Detail)
  {
      q = q.Include(x => x.c).ThenInclude(y => y.d);
      q = q.Include(x => x.b);
  }
  return q;
}
```

My update method:

```
public A Update(A update)
{
// Commented is current fix
// update.b = null;
// update.c = null;
Update(update, true);
return update;
}

public void Update(Model model, bool save)
{
  SetQuery();
  Set.Update(model); //Set is DbSet
  if (save)
  {
    Context.SaveChanges(); // Context is DBContext
  }
}
```

---

**START OF ORIGINAL THREAD:**

I have a Database-first application/API. The model can be simplified(there are move navigational properties) to:

```cs
public class A
{
    // some properties
    public int SomeValue {get; set;}

    // navigational properties
    public virtual B b {get; set;}
    public virtual C c {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    // some properties

    // navigational properties
    public virtual D d {get; set;}
}

public class C
{
    //some properties
}
```

In my repository query to get class A, I'm including the properties B, C, D and so on.

The properties are used to create DTOs and so on.

The problem arises when trying to update an entity of class A.
The database has triggers that are used for logging.
When updating class A, there are appearing log entries(entities are unaltered) for changes to each of the navigational properties' tables. As an example, if I get an entity of A, and update the value of SomeValue, there will be changes to the tables for B, C and D.

The classes B, C and D in this case are never edited, and are only used to create DTOs and connecting relationships between entities.

How can I save changes to an entity of A without touching B, C, D and thus not trigger the database to make a log entry?

I have tried AsNoTracking() after the ".Include().thenInclude()..." part without success.

Comment: EF doesn't save unmodified entities. The application code is somehow telling EF that all related objects are modified, eg by using `Update(A)`. That's only meant to attach detached objects. EF Core doesn't need this to detect that an entity was modified

Comment: Using `AsNoTracking()` and `Include()` will only make things worse. `AsNoTracking()` disables change tracking so EF Core no longer knows which entities were modified and has to save all of them. `Include` has nothing to do with change tracking, it's used to force eager loading of related entities. In fact, if the entities *aren't* loaded, there won't be any changes to persist

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you, I will look into the update function immediately. To comment #2, I'm only using Include() now, the reason is to have the related entities from the query to construct DTOs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Currently using `Set.Update(model)` on entity of `A`, then calling `Context.SaveChanges()`. What function is the correct one to use, if not update? Also, edited the post to include a solution, but I think it's not the correct way to solve the issue.

Comment: The solution is equivalent to *not* using `Include()`. If you want to update things, you don't need `Include`. Why is `Update(model)` used at all though? Where does `model` come from? `Update` tells EF that the `model` object and *all* related objects are Modified. It's not needed when `model` is loaded from EF itself. EF will detect any changes by itself and generate SQL to persist only the changed properties. That's what change tracking means.

Comment: Please post your actual code. The solution quite likely is to delete a few lines of code, like `AsNoTracking()` and the explicit `Include()`s

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you a million for helping. The reason for the includes is to create DTOs after querying multiple tables(navigate by foreign key) of the database. Is it normal to have separate queries with different(or zero) uses of `Include()` for seperate situations? That's the only solution I can think of right now.

Comment: Post your code, don't describe it. If you use `aUpdate.b = null` you can't create those DTOs. `Is it normal to have separate queries` yes. Not just that, but different DbContexts and different entities for different scenarios. A DbContext isn't a model of the database. It's a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work meant to handle a specific scenario. Different scenarios may require very different classes, or different properties per class. A `Customer` for an e-Commerce site's catalog is very different from the accounting `Customer`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the query and update code in on the original post.

Comment: There are three ways to perform the update. [Identity Resolution in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution).